# How to know app is installed from particular link

Tags: ios, safari, uuid, idfa

We have an AppStore link in our web application and user can install app from AppStore. Use case is like:

- User browsing the website
- There is Campaign page with AppStore link
- User clicks on that link
- Navigated to AppStore
- User install the app

**Now I need to decide the below items:**

- Number of download that refer from Campaign on Landing Page
- Number of unique user of download that refer from Campaign on Landing Page

*[I have explored Google Analytics Campaign Measurement but I guess that is targeted for MobileAd Network]*

Please help me to find out a solution.

Thank you!

***[Update]***

Is [Web Referrers of App Analytics](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-acquisition-marketing/) relevant to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible.

Once the user clicks the link to the AppStore, you will never know if user installs or not. Because the App Store API would not notify you and shouldn't even do so (privacy & security issues)

The best you can do is count how many users clicked that link. But this does not correlate to app install.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you anything about Web Referrers of App Analytics.
And I am not looking for App Store API for sure.